# Proper CDR collecting process for asterisk CDR databases

Tags: database, asterisk

First of all sorry for this complex long problem explanation.

Currently I'm maintaining several `asterisk` servers which process calls. currently I'm collecting `CDR`s to centralized database hourly.

The main problem here is to track `copied` records and `new` records. In my setup each `asterisk` `CDR` table have `id` column as the *primary key*. So in centralized table I'm coping this `id` and also maintain a column to keep `server_name`. By using both `id` and `server_name` I can identify the last collected `id` number of each `asterisk` server and then collected all new `CDR`s which higher than that `id` number.

This process is not perfect since its not good to rely on that id will always increase. And also I need to convert this setup to `REST API` and stop using `id` for this.

Use `datetime` range to pick call records also not a good idea because I'm collecting `CDR`s hourly and what if there was ongoing call with `duration` more than 1 hour. `Asterisk` `CDR` insert records at the end of the call and `datetime` field is not always in ascending order.

I could use a *flag* called `copied` with using above `datetime` range and solve the missing record problem but it is not suit with `REST APT` since it is *stateless* and can't keep *flags*.

Now I'm ran out of ideas... and wondering is there better solution for this...

Hope some expert can help me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very specific scenario but anyway I'm going to post my solution here.

After analyzing some solutions I came up with one solution. I added new column called `inserttime` with default value `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` (If you use postgres then you may need to look as `statement_timestamp()`). So `inserttime` will act like id as well as time variable some I can use `API` to search `CDR` using date ranges.